# Способы избавиться от экранов загрузки в играх?

Tags: разработка-игр

Ну или хотя бы минимизировать их количество.

Comment: Ни вопрос, ни ответ не относятся к Юнити. Убрал лишние метки.

Comment: Если знания английского позволяют, рекомендую спросить на https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: На какой платформе?

Comment: @ТарасАтавин я задавал вопрос что бы самому на него ответить. Собственно был тег юнити указан который кромстер с вопроса убрал

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Один из способов -- сделать загрузку неявной на примере реализации из серии игр Tomb Raider.

Если присмотреться к игре, то там время от времени попадаются условные разделения локаций в достаточно открытом мире.

В таких переходах сам персонаж замедляется и делает некое действие. В случае с TR это

- медленное и аккуратное прохождение через узкий проход/дырку в стене или через просто узкую расщелину. (в такие моменты даже теряется управление. То есть нельзя остановиться и пойти обратно, она обязательно перейдет на "следующий уровень" )

В таких случаях можно сделать анимацию из нескольких частей. При помощи этих частей на медленных компьютерах можно останавливать анимацию в достаточно "природных" местах и это будет выглядеть нормально и не резать глаз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Это прохождение долгой канатной дорожки.
- Иногда это прохождение по "луже" грязи.

(искать примеры в игре и делать гифки было уже влом)

В данных двух примерах можно остановиться и пойти обратно, но это займет продолжительное время, за которое мы успеем выгрузить кусок одного уровня и подгрузить кусок другого.

Явные же экраны загрузки в TR используются только если никак нельзя сделать по-другому. Например, если подойти к костру и выбрать локацию для перемещения.

> Хотя при большом желании, даже здесь можно было бы сделать анимацию как Лара уходит "в закат" с одного уровня, а потом затемнение экрана и появление Лариски на новой территории где она приходит в какую-то начальную точку к костру. Но, видимо, это было сделать сложнее и разработчики решили не запариваться с этим :)

Если вооружиться данным принципом, можно минимизировать количество загрузок в вашей игре и подумать как в вашем случае возможно проделать то же самое.

На практике это можно сделать асинхронной подгрузкой сцены в ту, где мы сейчас находимся. Для реализации этого понадобятся знания из статей:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.html

мы делаем цепочку из сцен. 2 переходные сцены между уровней мы грузим в любом случае. Это нужно, что бы мы могли из одного уровня через расщелину заглядывать в другой :)

На практике это выглядит приблизительно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не нужно воспринимать слишком буквально в данном случае переходную сцену. Это может быть буквально всего 2 сцены, просто которые залезают одна в другую объектами.

Comment: в resident evil каком-то примерно так же было реализовано, только были не проходы, а двери

Comment: Если от екрана избавиться нельзя, нужно сделать его хоть немного интересным, как в скайриме или серии batman arkham

Comment: @bobtorus не играл ни в то ни в другое. В batman arkham судя по видео, там подгрузка осуществлялась во время диалогов по рации, правильно? А что было в скайриме?

Comment: @Andrew, В [Скайриме](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLF9D59F94E052A2A4) на экране появляется интересная/полезная информация о мире. В [Batman Arkham](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9txnWLjP9k) когда Бэтмена победили с ним ведут беседу.